# where does a typedef enum statement go in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

A basic question I fear. The following code works, and the typedef enumeration is recognised, but I get a warning message "useless storage class specifier in empty declaration". Am I doing something wrong here and is this the best place to put a typedef enum?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CoreDataBaseTableViewController.h"

typedef enum ColourType {
    BACKGROUND=1,
    LOW=2,
    HIGH=3,
    EXTRA=4
};

@interface ColourList : CoreDataBaseTableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {

    NSManagedObjectContext* moc;    
    NSFetchedResultsController* fetchedResultsController; 

    ...

    enum ColourType colourTarget;

}

...
```

Comment: Which line is the warning pointing to?

Comment: got two, and the start and the end of the typdef but problem is sorted now.

Comment: Check out [NS_ENUM](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/) while you're at it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can put an enumeration anywhere in Objective-C which is valid in C. Where you have it now (above the interface) is a common place for enumerations which should be globally available. The warning is because you are using `typedef`, but don't actually define a type. If you simply want to create an enumeration, it isn't necessary. You just use:

```
enum ColourType {
    BACKGROUND=1,
    LOW=2,
    HIGH=3,
    EXTRA=4
};
```

You use `typedef` to define a type, which makes it easier to reference commonly used structures/unions/enumerations/other types. If you choose to do this, you should place a name for the type after the enumeration definition, and then you can reference the enumeration by using that name without the `enum` keyword.

```
typedef enum ColourType {
    BACKGROUND=1,
    LOW=2,
    HIGH=3,
    EXTRA=4
} MyColourType;
MyColourType colour;
```

Alternatively, you can create the enumeration and type in separate commands with the same effect.

```
enum ColourType {
    BACKGROUND=1,
    LOW=2,
    HIGH=3,
    EXTRA=4
};
typedef enum ColourType MyColourType;
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. Things are a lot clearer. In FORTRAN77 we didn't have these so its all new good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

By the by, consider using Objective-C's `NS_ENUM` macro. Take it away, 
[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW6)
*::polite applause as AD takes the mic::*

> The `NS_ENUM` and `NS_OPTIONS` macros provide a concise, simple way of defining enumerations and options in C-based languages. These macros improve code completion in Xcode and explicitly specify the type and size of your enumerations and options. Additionally, this syntax declares enums in a way that is evaluated correctly by older compilers, and by newer ones that can interpret the underlying type information.

Syntax example:

```
  typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, DRWColourType) {
  DRWColourTypeBackground,
  DRWColourTypeLow,
  DRWColourTypeHigh,
  DRWColourTypeExtra
};
```

Why? [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/):

> This approach combines the best of all of the aforementioned approaches, and even provides hints to the compiler for type-checking and switch statement completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Either get rid of `typedef`, or provide an alias for the type:

```
typedef enum X {...} Y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work just fine since objective c is just a superset of C. You must provide an alias for your enum like so:

```
typedef enum ColourType {
    BACKGROUND=1,
    LOW=2,
    HIGH=3,
    EXTRA=4
} MyColourType;
```