# Why should I declare enums at top level?

Tags: objective-c, enums

I'm confused where to put my `typedef enum` statements in my Objective-C header file. The standard seems to be right after the `#import` statements, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654809/where-does-a-typedef-enum-statement-go-in-objective-c) but I'm curious why that's the case. Why not in the `@interface` section?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you put them in the `@interface` section, enums will still be globally available. Since they're not really part of the `@interface`, you might as well put them outside of it.